# How to fix fatal error on startup in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I was just about to open RStudio, and pick up where I left off but suddenly it won't open anymore. It always comes up with these error messages:

I am running MacOS Sonoma Beta 1. I tried updating to a daily RStudio build but that doesnt help either. I created a second user profile on my mac and RStduio works fine there.

This is my error:

```
2023-06-26T11:45:09.188670Z [rsession-lor] WARNING ASSERTION FAILED:
 !posix::pthread_mutex_unlock(&m); LOGGED FROM: void rstudio_boost::recursive_mutex::unlock() 
/Users/user193109/opt/rstudio-tools/x86_64/boost/boost_1_78_0/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:113 2023-06-26T11:45:09.189044Z [rsession-lore] WARNING ASSERTION FAILED: px != 0; LOGGED FROM: typename rstudio_boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio_boost::signals2::mutex>::operator*() const [T = rstudio_boost::signals2::mutex] 
/Users/user193109/opt/rstudio-tools/x86_64/boost/boost_1_78_0/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:780 2023-06-26T11:45:09.189044Z [rsession-lor] WARNING ASSERTION FAILED: px != 0; LOGGED FROM: typename rstudio_boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio_boost::signals2::mutex>::operator*() const [T = rstudio_boost::signals2::mutex] /Users/user193109/opt/rstudio-tools/x86_64/boost/boost_1_78_0/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:780
```

Searched the whole web

Comment: Sonoma is beta software and usually R Studio takes some updating to be compatible with new versions of MacOS. Either downgrade to the current released OS or wait a few months for R Studio to be updated.

Comment: Check for and move (don't load) or delete `.Rdata` and/or `*.Rproj` files in the current or home directories.

Comment: I did but still the same error. What confuses me, that it works fine on the other user profile